# How can I append a string to an incoming url when someone visits the root of my website?

Tags: .htaccess, url, arguments, url-rewriting, href

I'm trying to get the string /index.php?page=home behind the adress in de adressbar when people visit the root of my site.

I tried rewrite rules in .htaccess but it redirects to the .php without any css etc.
Like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=home
```

I tried javascript rewrite but it reloads the page
Like this:

```
window.location.href = "/index.html?page=home"
```

My page already takes the arguments and follow a javascript function, but I would like to just simply add something to the current URL in the bar, without reloading or doing anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: Well, I don't necessarily need it on the homepage, but for example if i would click on my page to: contact, i'd like to change the url to append ?page=contact. So when they want to share the specific page, they can copy it and the recipient would go there directly..

Comment: isn't this automatically done if you click on a link at your page? Or do you save the current displayed page in a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it, you'll have to use the hash to do what you want. You can go from `http://example.com/#home` to `http://example.com/#contact` without reloading the page, but you cannot go from `http://example.com/index.php?page=home` to `http://example.com/index.php?page=contact` without reloading the page.

You can set and read from the hash using window.location.hash in javascript.

Comment: thanks, that'll probably do. Any suggestions how to rewrite it as a pretty /home and /contact? Those .htaccess regular expressions are a pain..

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not currently possible and I'm not sure if it'll be possible any time soon (or ever, for that matter). The best you can do is similar to what Twitter and Facebook do by using something like `http://example.com/#!/home`.